# issues with gas-preprocessor and ffmpeg4iphone

Tags: iphone, video, ios5, ffmpeg

I want to install gas pre-processor on my mac from 
[gas pre-processor](https://github.com/yuvi/gas-preprocessor/)

it is told that i have to install in usr/local/bin, But I didnt find my local folder in usr thats why I created a local/bin under usr then tried to install it from terminal...

but It didnt work.. it says that "Unrecognized input filetype at gas-preprocessor.pl line 33."

BTW my ultimate goal is to build ffmpeg4iphone in my xcode 4.2 and iOS5 sdk from [ffmpeg4iphone](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg4iphone/)